# Fill text after canny detection

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ocr, tesseract, canny-operator

Now I have an image that contains some text and it has a colored background , I want to extract it using **tesseract** but first i want to replace the colored background with white one and make the text itself black to increase the accuracy of detection process .
i was trying to use **Canny Detection**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image=cv2.imread('tt.png')
cv2.imshow('input image',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)


gray=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edged=cv2.Canny(gray,30,200)
edged = cv2.bitwise_not(edged)
cv2.imshow('canny edges',edged)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

that worked fine to replace the colored background with white but made the text's color white with black outlines (check the below images) .
so is there any way to make the whole text colored black  ?
or 
is there another way i can use to make that ?

[before Canny detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCQqn.png)

[after Canny detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XfQG.png)

**Edit**

the image may has mixed background colors like 
[input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVmDf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You should simply do it by using `THRESH_BINARY_INV`, it is the code:

```
cv::namedWindow("Original_Image", cv::WINDOW_FREERATIO);
cv::namedWindow("Result", cv::WINDOW_FREERATIO);
cv::Mat originalImg = cv::imread("BCQqn.png");

cv::Mat gray;
cv::cvtColor(originalImg, gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cv::threshold(gray, gray, 130, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV);

cv::imshow("Original_Image", originalImg);
cv::imshow("Result", gray);
cv::waitKey();
```

And it is the result:

[image]

You can play with the threshold value (130 in the above example).

Note: The code is in C++, if you are using Python, then you can go the same steps, and is that.

Good Luck!!

Comment: thank you for your help 
but my image have mixed background colors (white and blue ) so i want to do something generic that can convert any image with any background color to white one

Comment: Then you should provide more samples images to others to know the exact situation.